# Illustrator CS6 Gradient in Logo

Tags: graphics, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, gradient

I am looking to create an effect similar to this:

[image]

Is it even a gradient or some other effect. I'm not used to Illustrator, but require a vector based logo. I cannot seem to figure out the gradient effect and can only come with the below.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a gradient.  For want of a better way to explain it, it is two copies of the same "logo", where one is darker than the second.  The darker one is cut away and lain atop the first.

If you notice, the darker portion of the logo ascribes part of a circle.  If you are familiar with Photoshop, using layers, and basic brushes, then follow this.  If you were to create those three letters using the light gray, then select only those three letters, create a new layer, and then create a dark gray circle, copy only the portion you want, and paste it on another layer.
[image]

You would use pretty much the same technique.

**EDIT** Except you wouldn't screw up and leave a small amount of feather on the selection tool like I did :(

Comment: Thanks for the response, Illustrator seem vastly different to the Photoshop toolset despite being able to perform similar tasks. The reason it needs to be in Illustrator as it needs to be a vector format and scale up for print use with no distortion.